# Are Windows programs allowed to see which other programs are running and their Taskbar Names?

Tags: windows

Are Windows programs allowed to see which other programs are running and their Taskbar Names? For example is Program X allowed to see that Word 2016 is open, running, and editing `My Document.docx`?

Comment: I have not seen this in native applications. You would need to write a psecex-like macro to do this.

Comment: @John The native task manager shows this information (if you add "Command Line" to the process column) ... so yes, it is allowed.

Comment: Yes. I assumed the question was about non-task manager programs

Comment: See `tasklist /v` so yes.